# static final's and multiple classloaders

Tags: java, static, classloader, final

I have a definition like this

```
public static final Object foo = Xyz.generateFoo();
```

And my application is using multiple custom class loaders. How can I ensure that all classes see the same instance of `foo`?

Preferrably without resorting to external storage (ie System.Properties or file). Thanks.

Comment: Storing the date in file won't assure the same instance of foo in any way. Also, classloaders normally feature tree structure, anything loaded by a parent classloader will be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a reference to the value in a class loaded by a common parent class loader.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no way to ensure it if some of your custom classloaders violate the "check parent classloader first" rule (for example, as webapp classloaders do).

Otherwise you can place that field to the class loaded by parent classloader, as suggested by Tom Hawtin.

Answer (score 0):

Is that you want the return of this `Xyz.generateFoo();`  to be same all the time or after assigning to the variable `public static final Object foo = Xyz.generateFoo();`  you want to access the same instance ever where.